# URL redirect .htaccess - keep query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file set up which redirects several URL's - e.g:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sd\.mynewsite\.com\.au\/\$1" [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works fine - but it keeps appending `$1` to the end

So going to: `mysite.com.au` - goes to `sd.mynewsite.com.au/$1`

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers

Comment: Remove all those backslashes in your substitution URL – that part is _not_ a regular expression, so that kind of escaping is just plain wrong there. (And also the quotes are unnecessary.)

Comment: And your pattern will only match a request for the base URL, not any path – is that intended? And btw., when using RewriteRule in .htaccess context, the path that the pattern gets tested against _never_ starts with a slash either, that has been stripped off at that point already.